# How can be a post "created_date" be furhter one of its comment "created_date"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm analysing some Facebook posts. But I found something strange.

If you open the FB Graph API explorer and ask for the following path:

107111802663853_1319538284754526?fields=created_time,comments{created_time,message},permalink_url

you will get the information about the post with ID 107111802663853_1319538284754526.

If you look at the "created_date" fields, it says that the post has been created on 2016-12-28T21:00:00+0000 and the first comment (with ID 1319538284754526_1354491851259169) is dated 2016-12-28T12:46:24+0000

How can it be possible that the comment is earlier than the creation date?

For this post I found 77 comments, 58 of them appear to have a creation date earlier than the creation date of the post!

Here my code by which I'm doing this verification:

```
start_date = dateToTimestamp(data.created_time);
disp(data);
comments = data.comments;
sequence = zeros(size(comments));
for c=1:length(comments)
    disp(comments{c}.created_time);
    day = dateToTimestamp(comments{c}.created_time);
    sequence(c) = day-start_date;

end
```

The functiopn dateToTimestamp() is

```
function day = dateToTimestamp(d)

day = datetime(d,'TimeZone','local','Format','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ssZ');
day = int32(posixtime(day));
```

And I check by

```
sum(sequence<0)
```

Comment: One of the many assumptions that programmers get wrong: time can only go forwards.

Comment: A cleaner way to verify [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=107111802663853_1319538284754526%3Ffields%3Dcreated_time%2Ccomments%7Bcreated_time%2Cmessage%7D%2Cpermalink_url&version=v2.8). No need for the matlab code.

Comment: Braiam, I checked at the link you suggest. Indeed it is included in my question and it confirms that the date of the comment is earlier to the date of the post.